# UISwipeGestureRecognizer blocked by UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view which needs to handle pan, tap, and swipe gestures. I have pan and tap working, but when I add swipe, it doesn't work. Curiously, it seems that tap somehow blocks the swipes because if I remove the tap, then swipe works fine. Here's how I create my gesture recognizers.

```
- (void) initGestureHandlers
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeftGesture:)];
    swipeLeftGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRightGesture:)];
    swipeRightGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}
```

A lot of blog suggest using requireGestureRecognizerToFail to handle the case where tap fires before the double tap fires, so I tried that, but it also didn't work.

```
    [tapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeLeftGesture];
    [tapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRightGesture];
```

How can I get tap and swipe in the same view?

Comment: How do you want them to interact? They should all be able to work all the time or there should be some dependencies?

Comment: remove numberOfTouchesRequired & setNumberOfTapsRequired it not nessary for singel tap gesture and swipe gesture

Comment: I want the tap handler to fire when I tap, I want the swipe handler to fire when I swipe. Right now the swipe handler doesn't fire.

Comment: @Wain I want my swipe handler to fire first but I always end up getting touch gesture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

comment or remove the lines

```
 //[tapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeLeftGesture];
 //[tapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeRightGesture];
```

Also set the all the guesture objects delegate to self. like this

```
- (void) initGestureHandlers
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeftGesture:)];
    swipeLeftGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeftGesture.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRightGesture:)];
    swipeRightGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
swipeRightGesture = self;
    swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    [tapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
tapGesture.delegate = self;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
panGesture.delegate = self;
}
```

Implement the delegate method like this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: that was it! I hadn't set the delegate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

put this one and try it,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: nope, I wish it was that easy. And if it was, I don't want my tap handler to fire when I'm doing a swipe.

Comment: Your answer should have worked except I hadn't set the delegate. Doh!